# is it correct way to bind multiple values inside ngFor?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

trying to understand how to bind input values in `ngFor` in below code both are printing same values , trying to set different value for each input , where i am making mistake ?

app.comp.html

```
 <div *ngFor="let ques of sub.question">
   <label for="subQuestionsInput">{{ques.questionText}}</label>
   <input type="subQuestionsInput" class="form-control" *ngIf= "ques.answerType === 'TEXT_NUMBER'" name="TEXT_NUMBER" placeholder="Enter Dose amount Left" [(ngModel)]="TEXT_NUMBER"> 
   <input type="subQuestionsInput" class="form-control" *ngIf= "ques.answerType === 'TEXT_DATE'" name="TEXT_DATE" placeholder="Enter Next Dose Date" [(ngModel)]="TEXT_DATE"> 
</div>
```

app.comp.ts

```
import {
    Component,
    OnInit
} from '@angular/core';
import {
    ApiService
} from './api.service';
import {
    EventService
} from './format-questions/format-questions.service'
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent Implement OnInit {
      TEXT_NUMBER: string;
      TEXT_DATE: string;
    constructor(private dataService: ApiService, private eventService: EventService) {}
    ngOnInit() {
        console.log(TEXT_NUMBER);
      console.log(TEXT_DATE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Reactive Forms?

Comment: @LeandroHernándezMira we are using bootstrap

Comment: Have you checked reactive forms?

Comment: I think something is missing, where did you define `sub.question`?.

Comment: I am positive that what causes on printing same value is on your `sub.question`